# Sort JSON by names and not values

Tags: javascript, java, json

I'm running a query in java to get the quantity of calls in a time interval, the result of this query is:

```
  Date(dd/mm/yyyy)     |    calls
  _____________________|___________
  17/05/18             |    30
  16/05/18             |    36
  10/05/18             |    14
  27/04/18             |    12
  26/04/18             |    90
```

But when I plot the result using chart js, data is displayed in the order as belows

```
  Date(dd/mm/yyyy)     |    calls
  _____________________|___________
  10/05/18             |    14      
  26/04/18             |    90
  27/04/18             |    12
  16/05/18             |    36
  17/05/18             |    30
```

¿How do I sort this JSON by date using javascript?

```
{2018-05-10: "14", 2018-04-26: "90", 2018-04-27: "12", 2018-05-16: "36", 2018-05-17: "30"}
```

Comment: By date, or by number of calls in the interval?

Comment: Please show code responsible for fetching this data and how you're initializing your chart.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON is not valid. Those property names (the dates) must be quoted as strings for it to be valid.

Now, the best way to approach this is to actually change the JSON you're producing to an array:

```
data = [
    { "date": "2018-05-10", "hits": "14" },
    { "date": "2018-04-26", "hits": "90" },
    // etc
];
```

If you produce this on the server, which should be easy to change, then processing it in the client should be a lot easier. In fact, if you can format your dates on the server as `YYYY-MM-DD` then, given the above, Chart.js should automatically understand it as a date and you can simply map it to the `x` axis with something like...

```
let data = ... // The array above
let chartData = data.map(function(p) {
    return { x: p.date, y: p.hits };
});

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: '...',
    data: chartData,
    // etc
});
```

If for whatever reason you cannot change the format of the JSON produced (but, of course, you still quote the dates to make the JSON valid), then you could try something like this:

```
let data = ... // Your JSON corrected to be valid

let chartData = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
    let date = k.split('/').reverse().join('-');
    return { x: date, y: data[k] };
});

var chart = new Chart({
    type: '...',
    data: chartData,
    // etc
 });
```